# How can I run setInterval in background in expo using expo-task-manager

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing one app using react-native and expo in which I have one stopwatch where I am using setInterval to update stopwatch timer its working fine in foreground but when I minimize the app the timer stop working. 
After reading lot of documents I found that using `expo-task-manager` we can run things in background but I don't know how to use it with setInterval.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately setInterval can not run  when app is in back ground, you can do it with AppState listeners, so when your app goes in background and come in foreground calculate the time difference and use setState/useState methods.. to maintain a state..